# The Interaction between std::array, std::vector, and std::copy

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, containers

I am trying to copy a `std::array` into a `std::vector` using `std::copy`.

According to the cppReference, the prototype of `std::copy` is:

```
std::copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first)
```

, where `OutputIt d_first` stands for the beginning of the destination range.

By following the implementation, I have the following code:

```
std::array<int, 10> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

std::vector<int> vec;

std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), vec.begin());
```

However, the code did not work as I have expected, it simply does not copy the `array` into the `vector`.

Based on a quick googling, the code should be:

```
std::array<int, 10> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

std::vector<int> vec;

std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::back_inserter(vec));
```

My question is, why is the first code not working?

Is `vec.begin()` not considered as `OutputIt d_first`, in which my understanding would be "an iterator that represents the first position of the destination"?

Comment: Ask yourself: With `std::vector<int> vec;`, how many elements are in the vector?  How many objects did it create that can be assigned to?

Comment: Ask yourself, does the first position/element exist in the empty vector?

Comment: It’s an output iterator, but it points at the beginning of an empty range, so there’s no space to output to. An insert iterator knows how to extend the range for additional elements. Another approach would be to put enough elements into the vector to hold the copied elements: `vec.resize(10);` would do that.

Comment: Ah ! Thank you so much ! I know what I did wrong now.

Comment: When a vector `vec` is empty, `vec.begin()` is also `vec.end()`.  And you may not write values to `vec.end()`.

Comment: Note: in this scenario you should preferrably be using the constructor of `std::vector` for making this kind of copy, since this does prevent unnecessary reallocations and unnecessary initializations; this also allows for automatic deduction of the template parameter for `std::vector` (for >= C++17): `std::vector vec(arr.begin(), arr.end());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vec.begin()` *is* an output iterator and there is in principle no problem with using it in the way you are trying to. However `vec.begin()` is an iterator to the beginning of the range currently held by the vector. It is not an iterator that appends to the vector.

Since your vector is initially empty, the valid range to which `vec.begin()` refers is also empty, but you are then trying to assign multiple elements into that range with the `std::copy` call, causing undefined behavior.

On the other hand `std::back_inserter(vec)` is not an iterator over the range currently held by the vector, but instead a pure output iterator that appends a new element to the container each time it is assigned to.

Had you resized the vector before using `vec.begin()` to `std::copy` it would have been fine as well, since the range would to which `vec.begin()` refers would then be large enough to hold all of the elements from the array you are copying from:

```
std::vector<int> vec(arr.size());
std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), vec.begin());
```

---

You are also able to just write

```
std::vector<int> vec(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

which will directly determine the correct size to allocate for the vector's storage and copy the elements of the array into it. That is more efficient than either of the other two options.

---

Since C++17 you can also drop the value type if you want it to be equal to that of the array. It can be deduced via CTAD:

```
std::vector vec(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

---

Starting with C++23 you will also be able to just write

```
std::vector vec(arr);
```

for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::array<int, 10> arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::vector<int> vec;
std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), vec.begin());
```

> My question is, why is the first code not working?

It's because `vec` is empty. As soon as `std::copy` starts writing into it, it'll write out of bounds.

You'll either have to use the `back_inserter` which uses the container's `push_back` method to add elements - or `resize` the `vector` before doing the `copy`.